# examples of k-invariants of spectra

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The homotopy groups of commonly used topological spectra (like KO, S, MO, MSO, etc) are easy to find in literature, even appearing on Wikipedia's [List of Cohomology Theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cohomology_theories); however, I have had some difficulty finding descriptions of these spectra's k-invariants (aka Postnikov invariants). Does anyone have a reference detailing the k-invariants of common spectra? I'm particularly interested in the spectra noted above as well as MSpin and so-called Supercohomology ($\pi_0=\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_2=\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Comment: $MO$ has trivial k-invariants; it's a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra. That's the only one I know, though.